# Displacement Issue with Expandable Boxes in Multi-column Display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to display clickable and expandable boxes. When the width allows it, they are arranged in multiple columns. The problem is that I can't separate the columns; when I click on the box in the right column and it expands, the one at the bottom left drops down.

[Befor Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9dlz.png)
[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Yo6.png)

```
<body>

<div class='servers-container'>

<?php
foreach ($servers as $index => $server) {
    $statusVar = "ONOFF" . ($index + 1);
    $status = $$statusVar[0] ?? 0;
    $status_class = $status == 1 ? 'status-online' : 'status-offline';

    echo "<div class='server-ombre'>";
    echo "<details>";
    echo "<summary>";
    echo "Serveur {$server['name']}";
    echo "<span class='$status_class'>" . ($status == 1 ? 'En Ligne' : 'Hors Ligne') . "</span>";
    echo "<div id='server-div'>";
    echo "<div id='server-logo'>";
    echo "<img decoding='async' src='{$server['logo']}'>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id='presentation'>";
    echo "<div class='server-info'>";
    echo "<p>Ip : {$server['ip']}</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='server-info'>";
    echo "<p>Description : {$server['description']}</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</summary>";
    echo "<div class='down'>";

    $dataTypes = ['RAM', 'CPU', 'RX', 'TX'];
    foreach ($dataTypes as $type) {
        echo "<div class='chart-container'>";
        echo "<canvas id='myChart" . ($index + 1) . "{$type}'></canvas>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</details>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>

</div>

<script src="graph.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am currently using the  tag, but I've tried other techniques like JS, jquery etc... and made many attempts tweaking the CSS, yet I still encounter the problem. I think it might be due to the loop. Help me please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.